# How to query a gemesa-accumulo feature using command line

Tags: cql, accumulo, geomesa

I ingested data in geomesa accumulo using sfts and converters, Data was ingested successfully and i can visualise the same data using geoserver plugin. I want to filter feature data using command line but however not able to find any commands to do so. Please correct me if am wrong but i want to query feature data set just like done RDMS or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GeoMesa command line tools support querying via the 'export' command.  This command uses CQL (which is the same query language that GeoServer supports).

Check out these links for more about the GeoMesa export command.
http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/accumulo/commandline_tools.html#export

http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/accumulo/examples.html#exporting-features

For more about CQL, see the GeoTools (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/cql/cql.html) and GeoServer documentation (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html, and http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html).

Comment: Another option would be [spark SQL](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/spark/sparksql.html) for interactive query.